# How has the NSIndexPath initialization changed in Swift3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to follow along with Apple's [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift) tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1) and have almost completed it. I have had to amend several parts of the tutorial as I'm using Xcode 8 (which I think uses Swift 3 instead of Swift 2). However, I am running into the following compiler error and I don't know why:

`Argument labels (forRow:, inSection) do not match any available overloads`

in the following function:

```
@IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? MealViewController, meal = sourceViewController.meal {
        // Add a new meal
        let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: meals.count, inSection: 0)
        meals.append(meal)
        tableView.insertRows(at: newIndexPath, with: .bottom)
    }

}
```

I'm guessing that there is a different initialiser for NSIndexPath that's changed in Swift 3 but I can't find it. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry but as a new user of Swift and the Apple docs I thought I was doing a good job of researching. It would help if Apple would keep their tutorials up-to-date and bug free...

Comment: This question gets my plus one as neither code completion in Xcode 8, nor Apple's documentation supplied the answer easily.

Comment: this is a valid question!

Comment: Agreed with comments so far. It is not true to say that code completion or the docs answer this question (certainly not easily and for a beginner following the tutorial). Perhaps those saying so should check if it's correct before assuming they do. It's a valid question and should not be closed.

Comment: "Did you check the docs?" is almost never a valid response to an iOS or macOS question. For many of the APIs, Apple hasn't even written documentation yet. For all practical purposes, Stack Overflow *is* the Apple documentation. Code completion on Xcode is also notoriously bad.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`NSIndexPath` has been changed to `IndexPath`

try `IndexPath(row: Int, section: Int)`

[API Reference : indexpath](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexpath)

[Swift 3.0 Developer Preview](https://codeschool.com/blog/2016/07/11/swift-3-developer-preview/)

Comment: Weird how autocomplete doesn't work for `IndexPath` ...

Comment: Wait, does this mean NSIndexPath should no longer be used? I thought it was a subclass of IndexPath (idk the documentation doesn't outright say it)